# How to join two table without getting duplicate from both left & right table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

**Tables Details:**

CREATE TABLE Test2 (
ID INT,
Value INT,
other INT);

CREATE TABLE Test1 (
ID INT,
TYPE INT,
other INT);

INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (123456, 5, 12);
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (123456, 10, 17);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 00, 2);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 01, 6);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 02, 4);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (987654, 00, 7);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (987654, 01, 8);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (456789, 00, 6);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (456789, 01, 16);

**This is the Query i m using to avoid duplicate from table Test**

SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value
FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;

**Query Result:**

ID  TYPE    other   value
123456  0   2   5
123456  0   2   10
123456  1   6   5
123456  1   6   10
123456  2   4   5
123456  2   4   10

**Description:**

Expected Result is , when i m fetching match records from tables. Should get  the records from left table(Test1) without duplicate records and avoid duplicate record from right table (Test2).

**Reference Check Pic**

**Expected Query Result are,**

23456   0   2   5
123456  1   6   10
123456  2   4

**SQL Fiddle Link**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cd8a0/26

Criteria When there is ID match, should get  matched records from left table (Test1) without duplicate and from right table (Test2) without duplicate.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can JOIN the 2 tables ON their IDs, you'll probably need to introduce "artificial" rownumbers (as it were), and use these in your join, too.

TABLES and data

```
select * from test1 ;
+------+----+-----+
|ID    |TYPE|OTHER|
+------+----+-----+
|123456|0   |2    |
|123456|1   |6    |
|123456|2   |4    |
|987654|0   |7    |
|987654|1   |8    |
|456789|0   |6    |
|456789|1   |16   |
+------+----+-----+


select * from test2 ;
+------+-----+-----+
|ID    |VALUE|OTHER|
+------+-----+-----+
|123456|5    |12   |
|123456|10   |17   |
+------+-----+-----+
```

SELECT and ROW_NUMBER()

```
  select id, type, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by type ) rn_
  from test1 ;

+------+----+-----+---+
|ID    |TYPE|OTHER|RN_|
+------+----+-----+---+
|123456|0   |2    |1  |
|123456|1   |6    |2  |
|123456|2   |4    |3  |
|456789|0   |6    |1  |
|456789|1   |16   |2  |
|987654|0   |7    |1  |
|987654|1   |8    |2  |
+------+----+-----+---+

  select id, value, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by value ) rn_
  from test2 ;

+------+-----+-----+---+
|ID    |VALUE|OTHER|RN_|
+------+-----+-----+---+
|123456|5    |12   |1  |
|123456|10   |17   |2  |
+------+-----+-----+---+
```

If you now JOIN these 2 result sets, you may be a step closer to the solution that you are after.

```
select T1.id, T1.type, T1.other, T2.value
from (
  select id, type, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by type ) rn_
  from test1
) T1 left join (
  select id, value, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by value ) rn_
  from test2
) T2 on T1.id = T2.id and T1.rn_ = T2.rn_ ;

+------+----+-----+-----+
|ID    |TYPE|OTHER|VALUE|
+------+----+-----+-----+
|123456|0   |2    |5    |
|123456|1   |6    |10   |
|456789|0   |6    |NULL |
|456789|1   |16   |NULL |
|987654|0   |7    |NULL |
|987654|1   |8    |NULL |
|123456|2   |4    |NULL |
+------+----+-----+-----+
```

Now you just need to eliminate the rows whose IDs are *not* in Table2.

```
-- final query
select T1.id, T1.type, T1.other, T2.value
from (
  select id, type, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by type ) rn_
  from test1
) T1 left join (
  select id, value, other
  , row_number() over ( partition by id order by value ) rn_
  from test2
) T2 on T1.id = T2.id and T1.rn_ = T2.rn_
where exists ( select null from test2 where id = T1.id )
order by 1, 2 ;

+------+----+-----+-----+
|ID    |TYPE|OTHER|VALUE|
+------+----+-----+-----+
|123456|0   |2    |5    |
|123456|1   |6    |10   |
|123456|2   |4    |NULL |
+------+----+-----+-----+
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ed25fd1191d9cc9ba8404163f8e511e) (Oracle 18c)  [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cd8a/1) (Oracle 11g)